# Unity Networking Client not calling functions on server

Tags: unity-game-engine, rpc, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

i have a 2 player game. One user becomes  server the other client.I am calling the method "buttonclicked" from both the sides when they are connected to add a tower.

When the method "buttonclicked" is called from the side which becomes the server, code executes well and an enemy is generated on both the side which is the server and the one which is the client.

However when the same code is run from the client the enemy is not generated on the side which becomes the server.

Below is the code

```c#
 public void buttonclicked(int enemyID){
     CmdgenerateEnemies(enemyID);
 }

 [Command]
 public void CmdgenerateEnemies(int enemyID)
 {
    RpcgenerateEnemywithID(enemyID);
 }

 [ClientRpc]
 public void RpcgenerateEnemywithID(int enemyID)
 {
     enemyID = 1; // hardcoded for testing
     for(int i = 0; i < enemiesArray.Length; i++) 
     {
         GameObject enemy = enemiesArray [i];
         if(enemy.GetComponent<EnemyScript>().enemyId == enemyID) 
         {
             GameObject einstance = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoint1);
             einstance.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
             einstance.GetComponent<splineMove>().pathContainer = topPath[1];
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is you Network Identity set to Server Only?

Comment: @ZayedUpal : nops it is local player authority

Comment: I tried using default NetworkManager of Unity with Network GUI attached and it works correctly. I tested it out on mouse click. Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/q7GdGFfy

Comment: @ZayedUpal : i am also using the default networkmanager and defauly network GUI .. Were you able to generate the prefab from both the server and the client side ??

Comment: Please if you send the inspector screenshots of Network MAnager and the images

Comment: @muzammil yes, I was able to do so. Here's the screenshots of NetworkManager and The player. https://imgur.com/a/DCCDT

Comment: i am receiving a warning "Trying to send command for object without authority." Maybe that is creating issues

Comment: I had this same problem and resolved it by checking my build for all network-related errors are fixing those.